# Randomizing material across meshes - UE4

Tags: textures, rendering, unreal-4

I have multiple instances of the same mesh which is using the same material.

[image]

While looking for randomizing textures, I came across texture bombing and so the material in 1 wall looks fairly random. Its a blend of 2 materials. But the problem is different walls look the same. Is there some way so the walls look different with same material. For eg: The green moss is random across the walls and not look same?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can look at creating "Macro Texture Variation" with the "Reduce Macro Contrast" that will help with breaking up tiling.

Include Starter Content in your project, and open up "M_Brick_Clay_New" or try opening a few different materials in the StarterContent\Materials folder, and look for the commented block "Macro Texture Variation" and "Reduce Macro Contrast", you may simply copy/paste those nodes, and multiply the output from the final node, with your final base color node.

[image]